# How to access WordPress on xazmpp?

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I have a website online, however i want to set up a localhost to edit my site. I exported the SQL file as well as the entire WordPress files. I tried to install XAMPP to host my files. But after changing the port from 80 to 8080 i can view the test.html file in put into the folder i created on xampps. I know xampp connects to my file(s), but the WordPress files would load in.

first i made a copy of my website by exporting the database files THEN i copied all the WordPress files and transferred them to my desktop.

NEXT i installed XAMPP as mentioned before. i created a directory and transferred all my WordPress files to the new folder. Next i opened PHPadmin for the database-then i imported the database file. I cannot connect to localhost:8080/acb/wp-admin i get a message saying my database username or password in incorrect.

BUT all the files are EXACLY the same file live on the internet i don't understand, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xampp os for that by default your database username is 'root' and password will be '' (empty string) change this setting in your Wordpress site wp_config

```
/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );
```

like this. May it will be helpful for you.

Comment: does it matter if the username and password for the db is the same as my online site? i ask because the db's name online is the name of the db on xamapp.